# CAKEPHP 2.0, fill find condition array with variable conditions

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, find, conditional-statements

i am currently making a filter for one of my views. I want to fill the conditions array based on `if/else` statements that check the data i received from the url.

I am trying to build it somewhat like this. I will be creating multiple `if/else` statements. If the statement is true i want the condition to be filled like demonstrated below, else will keep the condition empty. The `find()` query in the else statement is being ran and creating the error.

```
//$set and $kleur are variables that come from the URL, they work
public function seriesfilter($foil='search', $color, $set, $name){
    $this->loadModel('Cards');
    $this->loadModel('Magicsets');
    $setname = $this->Magicsets->findByCode($set);
    $this->Card->recursive=-1;
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    $kleur = "%".$color."%";
    $condition = "'manaCost like' => $kleur";

    $conditions = array(
        'set' => $set,
        $condition
    );


    if ($foil == 'nonfoil'){
        if($color == 'all'){
        $cards= $this->Cards->find('all',array('fields'=>'multiverseid,name,nprice,nstock,set,rarity','conditions'=>array('set' => $set),'limit'=>750));
        }
        else{
            $cards= $this->Cards->find('all',array('fields'=>'multiverseid,name,nprice,nstock,set,rarity','manaCost','conditions' => $conditions,'limit'=>750));
        }
    }
```

Below you can see the error i receive

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> %R% LIMIT 750' at line 1

SQL Query: SELECT `Cards`.`multiverseid`, `Cards`.`name`, `Cards`.`nprice`, `Cards`.`nstock`, `Cards`.`set`, `Cards`.`rarity` FROM `magicmm`.`cards` AS `Cards` WHERE `set` = 'BNG' AND 'manaCost like' => %R% LIMIT 750
```

Any help in setting up multiple conditions would be great. I only want to add conditions to the conditions array that are received through url.

Kind Regards,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

There should be `'`s for `LIKE` condition. Try with -

```
$condition = "manaCost like '%$kleur%'";

$conditions = array(
    'set' => $set,
    0 => $condition
);
```

Comment: I have a qustion, Is it true that the first letter of the class name should be capitalized ? Or it does not matter anymore? *(in php)* Tnx

Comment: We should follow the conventions. For 2.x it is important for CakePHP to work Properly.

Comment: Wow, the script is working now! Thanks a lot. I tried many variations but i wasn't sure how quotes would be read by a find query if they came from a variable.